# Bootstrap 4 nav-link hover effect

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put a hover effect targeting the a-links in the navigation bar only (not the forwardslashes).
But I can't seem to access only the a-links, the effect ends up running along the whole navbar instead.
Seems to be a conflict with Bootstrap 4 here.

HTML

```
 <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
            <!-- <div class="mx-auto d-sm-flex d-block flex-sm-nowrap"> -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.facebook.com/GetMove.Official/">GET MOVE</a>
            <button
                class="navbar-toggler mr-left custom-toggler"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span> / </span><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#past-bookings">Archive<span> / </span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About<span> / </span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#subscribe">Newsletter<span> / </span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="mailto: hola@getmove.net">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-row justify-content-center flex-nowrap">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a
                            class="nav-link nav-social-icon"
                            target="_blank"
                            href="https://www.facebook.com/GetMove.Official/"
                            ><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i
                        ></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-social-icon" target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/getmovemx/"
                            ><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i
                        ></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-social-icon" target="_blank" href="https://soundcloud.com/getmove"
                            ><i class="fab fa-soundcloud"></i
                        ></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
.nav-item:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.nav-item:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle here
https://codepen.io/pen/WNNPdxv

Comment: Does `.nav-item` have `position:relative`?

Comment: The first place to start is add `.nav-item { position: relative }`. When you use `position: absolute` that element is positioned to the nearest parent element that has a position set.

Comment: Thank you! That almost solved it. The hover effect is now targeting the a-links. Suggestions how I can avoid targeting the spans containing the forward slashes that's within the a links? I've updated the fiddle as well.

Comment: You really can't avoid that unless you move the slashes *outside* of the `.nav-item` tag. Your underline is on the `li` item on hover. So if you look at your structure, your slash is inside of that element. The only way you can do this is if you change the markup or make it so the CSS only makes the width of the after element less than 100%, but it may not work for all links

Comment: I ended upp moving the slashes outside of the nav-item tags in the end. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I'm probably too late then, no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue you should not put separators inside the anchor elements.
Below is an approach which eliminates the extra HTML using the `content` property.
This is similar to Bootstrap's [breadcrumb](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/breadcrumb/).

But as you're already familiar, first some cleanup ^^

- remove the span separators from `nav-links`
- use the span for text nodes (could be handy to put the animation on there)
- move the animation from `:after` to `:before` (a separator is logically after an element, except for the last-child perhaps, this also gives you the elements width where you can now control the right position.)
- use the `:after` for the separator
- provide full width for the main navigation and use flexbox to align the space it's using (flex-end, center, space-between, ...)

### HTML changes

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-primary w-100 ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <span>Home</span>
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#past-bookings"><span>Archive</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>About</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#subscribe"><span>Newsletter</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="mailto: hola@getmove.net"><span>Contact</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-secondary flex-row justify-content-center flex-nowrap">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-social-icon" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/GetMove.Official/"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-social-icon" target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/getmovemx/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-social-icon" target="_blank" href="https://soundcloud.com/getmove"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### Solution

Now to solve the issue, place the animation on before and separator on the after pseudo elements.

```
.navbar-primary .nav-item:after {
    content: "/";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.25rem;
    left: auto;
    right: -0.5rem; /* control the amount of space for the separator */
}

.navbar-primary .nav-item:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.navbar-primary .nav-item:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
}
```

In case you want to change the character, you have only one editing place.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/v637aqpf/)

In case you want to change the animation without the padding I'd suggest to distract the `nav-link` padding using `calc()`.

```
.navbar-primary .nav-link:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0.5rem; /* nav-link padding-left */
    width: 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.navbar-primary .nav-link:hover:before {
    width: calc(100% - 1rem); /* minus nav-link padding left and right */
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/de9gtnb8/)

Comment: Thank you Tim! Very helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the hover on the a-link, and then a-link position:relative, or put the class position-relative to the a-link.

```
.nav-item a {
    position: relative;
}
.nav-item a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.nav-item a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't take the forward slashes into account I'm afraid.