# Override Bootstrap class "nav-item"

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have placed a hover underline effect on the nav-items in the navigation bar, but I would like to remove the effect from the social icons. I have tried to use several ways to get rid of the hover effect on the icons but none seem to work for instance I have tried to add !important or to add an extra class for the social icons or to define a class only for the a-links containing the page navigation links but Bootstrap 4 don't seem to let me.

For example I tried to add a "nav-a" class to the items that I would like to have the hover effect on:

```
.nav-item.nav-a {
    position: relative;
}

.nav-item.nav-a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.nav-item.nav-a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

CSS

```
.nav-item {
    position: relative;
}

.nav-slash {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.nav-item:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.nav-item:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
            <!-- <div class="mx-auto d-sm-flex d-block flex-sm-nowrap"> -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/GetMove.Official/">GET MOVE</a>
            <button
                class="navbar-toggler mr-left custom-toggler"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active nav-a">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <span class="nav-slash"> / </span>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-a">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#archive">Archive</a>
                    </li>
                    <span class="nav-slash"> / </span>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-a">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#guests">Guests</a>
                    </li>
                    <span class="nav-slash"> / </span>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-a">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#subscribe">Newsletter</a>
                    </li>
                    <span class="nav-slash"> / </span>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-a">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="mailto: hola@getmove.net">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-row justify-content-center flex-nowrap">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a
                            class="nav-link nav-social-icon"
                            target="_blank"
                            href="https://www.facebook.com/GetMove.Official/"
                            ><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i
                        ></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-social-icon" target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/getmovemx/"
                            ><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i
                        ></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-social-icon" target="_blank" href="https://soundcloud.com/getmove"
                            ><i class="fab fa-soundcloud"></i
                        ></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Codepen here:
https://codepen.io/pen/WNNPdxv

Comment: You should follow up my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939609/bootstrap-4-nav-link-hover-effect/58950670#58950670) since this issue is tackled there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use enough specificity for `:after`, and since the effect is on the `nav-item`, the special `nav-social-icon` class should be on `nav-item` instead of `nav-link`...

```
.nav-item.nav-social-icon:after {
     border-bottom: none;
}
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/Hb8EkxaPSA

Comment: I have tried this already, but it doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: What doesn't work: https://codepen.io/themesguide/pen/vYYPyQG ?

Comment: It works in the codepen, but when I implement the same code in my stylesheet it doesn't override.

Comment: Then you need to determine what's breaking it in the other environment. As far as the question of *"Override Bootstrap class “nav-item”"* .. it's been answered hasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the hover effect on the nav-item class, you can change the class for the social icons to something else (like: nav-social) so that they won't be affected.